# How to prevent EF4.1 from creating a DB if it doesn't exist?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF4.1 with MVC3 and I need an override to prevent EF from creating a db if it doesn't exist. Instead of creating a new db I would like to catch the error and report that the initial catalog (the database name) is invalid in the connect string.

However, during development I would like to allow for updates for new classes/properties to create according tables/cols in the database.

Is there a best practice or pattern here?

Answer (score 3):

In my application i am completly disable context initializer and handle database mapping and schema manually.

For example :

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext() : base("connection_string")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(null); // Important! Dont use entity framework initializer !important
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        /* Register custom mapping class */
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountMapper());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And custom mapping :

```
public class AccountMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Employee entity mapper
    /// </summary>
    public AccountMapper()
    {
        ToTable("accounts");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the EF database initializer, specifically the `IDatabaseInitializer` interface.

If you just want it to stop creating the database when it doesn't exist, then just set the Initializer to `null`. But if you want to log the event or something along those lines then simply create your own `IDatabaseInitializer` - it's not hard.

You can then set the initializer `Application_Start` in your global.asax.cs like so:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new YourCustomInitializer());
```

As a bonus, here's an example `IDatabaseInitializer` that I use to run database migrations (using [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator))... it's extremely handy if I do say so myself!

```
public class MigrationsDbContextInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<YourDbContext>
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MigrationsDbContextInitializer));

    public void InitializeDatabase(YourDbContext context)
    {
        var announcer = new BaseAnnouncer(x => Logger.Info(x));

        var runnerContext = new RunnerContext(announcer)
        {
            Database = "sqlserver2008",
            Connection = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString,
            Target = "YourEntitiesNamespace",
            PreviewOnly = false,
            Task = "migrate"
        };

        new TaskExecutor(runnerContext).Execute();
    }
}
```